# DataContractJsonSerializer Deserializing List<T>

Tags: c#, json, rest, serialization, deserialization

I am creating a Communication library for REST WCF Service. Communication class takes an object as argument serialize it and make a POST request to the REST service URL and waits for the response. After that response is deserialized and returned. I have a composite type as response class. This class has has three fields and one of them is a `List<T>` where `T` is another class. Problem is that it deserialization process work ok for the two field but the field that is a List generates always an empty list. There is no problem in Web service logic.

```
public class Communicate<RequestType, ResposeType>
    where ResposeType : class
    where RequestType : class
{

    public ResposeType CommunicateSvr(RequestType _parameter, string methodName, string serverIp)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer obj;
        WebClient Proxy1 = new WebClient();
        Proxy1.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializerToUplaod = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RequestType));
        serializerToUplaod.WriteObject(ms, _parameter);
        byte[] data = Proxy1.UploadData(serverIp + methodName, "POST", ms.ToArray());
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
        obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ResposeType));
        ResposeType _respons = obj.ReadObject(stream) as ResposeType;

        return _respons;
    }

}
```

Class Request

```
public class GetTransactionReq
{
    public string token { get; set; }
    public string fromDate { get; set; }
    public string toDate { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
}
```

Class Response

```
public class GetTransactionsPENALTY
{

    public bool test1 { get; set; }                 
    public int test2 { get; set; }          
    public int test3 { get; set; }    
    public int test4 { get; set; }

    public List<MinPenaltyTransaction> list { get; set; } 
}
```

I am doing something wrong or anything I should change ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are saying that list is of type `T`, but it's of type `MinPenaltyTransaction`.

Comment: Could you provide the `MinPenaltyTransaction` class?

Comment: For us to be of more help, please share the `MinPenaltyTransaction` class and the response JSON.  Otherwise, please take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923%28v=vs.110%29.aspx to make sure `MinPenaltyTransaction` is a supported type.